# Get Terms Path as per locale in SharePoint Online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, taxonomy, term-store, term

I am struggling to get terms path as per current locale.

I have proper settings in  SharePoint Term store for getting term label in  English, Italian and German languages. I am getting taxonomy labels as per current user locale.
But I have a scenario where I am using term.PathOfTerm to get full path of terms and this value is always coming in English language. I need translated term path as per current user locale.

**I am getting examples to use Term.GetPath(int LCID); to get localized path, but this gives me null values for all languages, even for English language(LCID 1033).**

It will be great help if someone knows the reason why I am getting null values or if we have any other ways to get translated term path.

An Immediate help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Neelam - Did you get any solution for this? I'm also facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing ExecuteQuery() call after you requesting it.
Here is a piece of PowerShell code which works fine with `GetPath` method:

```
$term = Get-PnPTerm -Identity 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 # Put your term id instead
$path = $term.GetPath(1033) # Here Value will NOT be populated
$term.Context.ExecuteQuery()
$pathValue = $path.Value # Here Value will be populated
```

Hope this will help you as PnP library is using CSOM internally.

It happens because `GetPath` returns `ClientResult<string>` object which requres a call back to server to be populated. For example, you can find similar examples (not related to terms) [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-follow-people-by-using-the-net-client-object-model-in-sharepoint) (See `ClientResult<bool> isFollowed = followingManager.IsFollowed(actorInfo);` example there)

Regards,
Alexandr